# Creating exact django db column for FK

Tags: django, django-models

I am having a problem creating a foreign key in my table. The foreign key table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_app_provider` (
  `provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `provider_slug` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`provider`),
  KEY `main_app_provider_75a6f163` (`provider_slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I do the generic `provider = models.ForeignKey('main_app.Provider')` I get an `errno:150`. How would I add a field in django with the **exact** criteria defined in provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_field` to specify the field that Django should use as the primary key.

```
provider = models.ForeignKey('main_app.Provider', to_field='provider')
```

Comment: Still, in django it's creating a latin1 table, which won't match to the utf8. How would I force utf8?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE ... CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` // `$ syncdb` worked here